# PrimeFaces Extension Sheet Restrict Decimal Places For Input

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I want to restrict decimal places up to 1. User shouldnt type multiple dots(1..99) and (1.99). I want 1.9 2.6 for ex. Not 2.66 then convert into 2.7 etc. I have to use pe:sheetcolumn. I tried to add p:inputnumber and other p: components than pe extension. But pe:sheetcolumn have to be. With below approach it just let user to type multiple dots and multiple decimal places. It just convert to 1 decimal after user entered value on screen with #0.0. But i want to restrict on input to type multiple decimal places than 1 and multiple dots. I thought about javascript keyup event but i think it would be bad approach. How can i achive that

```
<pe:sheetcolumn headerText="SOME" value="#{SOME.some}" colWidth="200"
                        colType="numeric" numericPattern="#0.0" >
        </pe:sheetcolumn>
```

For example for p:inputNumber as you can see on image user cant type multiple dots and they cant add decimal places more than 6.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOeg.png)

I want to do same thing with pe:sheetColumn. How can i do that

My JSF VERSION : 2.2.1 PRİMEFACES AND PRIMEFACES EXTENSION VERSION : 6.2

Comment: ON the showcase example:https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf  if you go to the Price column and enter "5.7.7" it won't let you leave the cell because it knows the number is invalid.  The same is not happening for you?

Comment: @Melloware It's not letting me leave the cell too. But customer wants that restrict user typing there.  Like for ex they shouldnt type 5.7.7 to there or 2.99.  How can i do that ? I tried onvalidate or jsf  validate properties. But all let user to enter 5.7.7. I dont want that. So customer is :)

Comment: OK give me some time I think I can post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install this MonkeyPatch you can then tweak the output to do whatever your want.   I am pretty sure you can get the current cell with `var currentValue = this.getDataAtCell(row , col)`  If you add this JS to your app you can then tweak how it handles keypresses and validation.

I added this line for you

```js
 var currentValue = this.getDataAtCell(row , col); // VALUE HERE!
```

So you can validate whatever your want with your code and if there is already a "." don't accept another "." etc.

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.ExtSheet) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.ExtSheet.prototype.handleHotBeforeKeyDown = function(e) {
        var selectedLast = this.getSelectedLast();
        if (!selectedLast) {
            return;
        }
        var row = selectedLast[0];
        var col = selectedLast[1];
        var celltype = this.getCellMeta(row, col).type;
        var currentValue = this.getDataAtCell(row , col); // VALUE HERE!

        var evt = e || window.event; // IE support
        var key = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode || 0;
        var shiftDown = e.shiftKey;

        // #740 tab on last cell should focus this next component
        if (this.allowTabOffSheet && key == 9) {
            var lastRow = this.countRows() - 1;
            var lastCol = this.countCols() - 1;
            if ((!shiftDown && row === lastRow && col === lastCol) ||
                (shiftDown && row === 0 && col === 0)) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                this.unlisten();
                this.deselectCell();

                //add all elements we want to include in our selection
                var focusableElements = 'a:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), input[type=text]:not([disabled]):not([hidden]):not([aria-hidden="true"]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"]):not([aria-hidden="true"])';
                if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form) {
                    var focusable = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.activeElement.form.querySelectorAll(focusableElements),
                        function(element) {
                            //check for visibility while always include the current activeElement
                            return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === document.activeElement
                        });
                    var index = focusable.indexOf(document.activeElement);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        var nextElement = focusable[index + 1] || focusable[0];
                        nextElement.focus();
                    }
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        // prevent Alpha chars in numeric sheet cells
        if (celltype === "numeric") {
            // #766 do not block if just CTRL or SHIFT key
            if (key === 16 || key === 17) {
                return;
            }

            // #739 allow navigation
            var ctrlDown = evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey; // Mac support
            if (shiftDown || ctrlDown) {
                // navigation keys
                if (key == 9 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // check for cut and paste
            var isClipboard = false;
            // Check for Alt+Gr (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)
            if (ctrlDown && evt.altKey) isClipboard = false;
            // Check for ctrl+c, v and x
            else if (ctrlDown && key == 65) isClipboard = true; // a (select all)
            else if (ctrlDown && key == 67) isClipboard = true; // c
            else if (ctrlDown && key == 86) isClipboard = true; // v
            else if (ctrlDown && key == 88) isClipboard = true; // x

            // allow backspace, tab, delete, enter, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers
            // ONLY home, end, F5, F12, minus (-), period (.)
            // console.log('Key: ' + key + ' Shift: ' + e.shiftKey + ' Clipboard: ' + isClipboard);
            var isNumeric = ((key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 13) ||
                (key == 46) || (key == 110) || (key == 116) ||
                (key == 123) || (key == 188) || (key == 189) ||
                (key == 190) || ((key >= 35) && (key <= 40)) ||
                ((key >= 48) && (key <= 57)) || ((key >= 96) && (key <= 105)));

            if ((!isNumeric && !isClipboard) || shiftDown) {
                // prevent alpha characters
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```